# Factory Boy: how to set conditional SubFactory() attribute depending on params

Tags: django, pytest, factory

I got a Customer model which is related to a Company model. I'd like to give my factory the possibility to use a given company (if I need several customer from the same company). I thought to use the inner class Params to achieve that, but I got an issue using LazyAttribute and SubFactory together. Here is my factory:

```
class CustomerFactory(UserFactory):
   """
   To be valid, customer needs to belong to one of these groups:
       - manager
       - regular
   This can be achieved using the `set_group` parameter.

   Example:
       manager = CustomerFactory(set_group=manager_group)

   """
   
   @lazy_attribute
   def _company(self):
       if self.use_company:
           return self.use_company
       else:
           return SubFactory('rdt.tests.factories.CompanyFactory')

   class Meta:
       model = Customer

   class Params:
       use_company = None

   @post_generation
   def set_group(self, create, extracted, **kwargs):
       if extracted:
           self.groups.add(extracted)
```

I thought to use the factory as:

```
c1 = factories.CustomerFactory(use_company=my_company)
 
c2 = factories.CustomerFactory()
```

I got ValueError. It seems I can't get the parameter value 'use_company' in the factory.

Anyway my factory throws a ValueError.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution simply using an other post_generation method like this:

```
    @post_generation
    def set_group(self, create, extracted, **kwargs):
        if extracted:
            self.groups.add(extracted)

    @post_generation
    def company(self, create, extracted, **kwargs):
        if extracted:
            self._company = extracted
            self.save()
```